# Execute Python Script from PHP and Keeping Script Open

Tags: python, php, bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am creating a project on a raspberry pi using a motion detector to send a text message. Having some issues executing a python script from PHP (Apache2).

Trying to execute this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
import time
import os
#Motion sensor in GPIO23
ms = MotionSensor(23)

def send_notification():
    #Debug Motion Statement
    print("There was a movement!")

    #Notification script is stored in notification variable
    notification = os.popen ('bash /home/pi/project/notification.sh')

    #Send Notification
    print(notification.read())

    #Delay between notifications
    time.sleep(15)

#Execute send_notification function on motion
ms.when_motion = send_notification
```

The notification.sh script for reference. It uses postfix to send a text message.

```
echo "Motion was detected in your Smart Mailbox!" | mail myphonenumber@vtext.com
```

From this PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Smart Mailbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<div class="form-style-5">
    <body style="text-align:center;">
        <h1>Smart Mailbox Application</h1>
        <p>Enter Your Phone Number:</p>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="tel" name="phonenumber" placeholder="10 Digit Phone Number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
            <br>
            <p>Select Your Phone Carrier:</p>
            <select name="carrierdropdown" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Verizon">Verizon</option>
                <option value="ATT">ATT</option>
                <option value="Sprint">Sprint</option>
                <option value="TMobile">T-Mobile</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start SmartMailbox">
        </form>

    </body>
</div>

</html>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //Appends phone carrier address to email address
            if($_POST['carrierdropdown']=="Verizon"){
                //echo "DEBUG:Verizon";
                $carrier = "@vtext.com";
            } elseif ($_POST['carrierdropdown']=="ATT"){
                //echo "DEBUG:ATT";
                $carrier = "@txt.att.net";
            } elseif ($_POST['carrierdropdown']=="Sprint"){
                //echo "DEBUG:Sprint";
                $carrier = "@messaging.sprintpcs.com";
            } elseif ($_POST['carrierdropdown']=="TMobile"){
                //echo "DEBUG:T-Mobile";
            } else{
                echo "Break";
            }

        //Gets users phone number from HTML form
        $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];

        //Opens notification script for editing
        $file = fopen('/var/www/html/notification.sh','w');

        //Writes mail command to file appending phonenumber
        fwrite($file,'echo "Motion was detected in your Smart Mailbox!" | mail ' . $phonenumber . $carrier);

        //Closes file
        fclose($file);

        //Runs python scripts
        exec('node /home/pi/project/blynkconnect.js');
        exec('python -i /home/pi/project/MotionNotification.py &');

    }
?>
```

This following command works on the command line alone. I have to use the -i flag so that the session will stay open to detect motion.

```
python -i /home/pi/project/MotionNotification.py &
```

So I suppose my issue is running this from PHP (I am using apache2 web server to host). All files have read,write,execute permissions. The node command I am running from PHP works flawlessly FYI. I have tried to give the apache web user root access and still no luck.

Any ideas I can give a try? Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that PHP would in theory run your python script at each page load regardless if a instance is still running?

Comment: That wouldn't be a huge deal, it would still satisfy my requirement. In the future I would try to find a solution to kill the process on a button click.

Comment: Try to check if www-data can run it (Do some logging)